# XSLT close parent tag, fix malformed HTML

Tags: xml, html, xslt

Lets suppose I have the following XML input:

```
<para>
  text before
  <sometag>Content</sometag>
  text after
</para>
```

I wish to transform this content into HTML. I have the following two XSLT rules:

```
<xsl:template match="para">
  <p>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sometag">
  <div>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

The input XML is fix. There really is no workaround to my current knowledge, "sometag" needs to be transformed into a div HTML element. Obviously this is not he common, or recomended use, but it is allowed by the DTD. This would result in the following output:

```
<p>
 text before
 <div>
  Content
 </div>
 text after
</p>
```

Which is of course an invalid HTML, as "p" can not contain "div".

If I open a file that contains such invalid XML in a browser it will autofix this malformed HTML to look like this:

```
<p>
 text before
</p>
<div>
 Content
</div>
<p>
 text after
</p>
```

What happened here of course, is that the "p" elements were closed before the "div" elements started.

Please keel in mind that the output should be HTML5.

My question is that is it possible to do this in XSLT2.0? If not, is there any Java library that would do this? If so please add a sample, I have seen similar questions but the answer was only a link to a library and none seem to do exactly this.

Comment: What do you want to do? Insert the </p> before the <div> with xslt, or allow the <div> inside the <p>?

Comment: Well something like the former would be great.

Comment: Wouldn't changing `<sometag>` to `<span>` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="if (self::text()) then 1 else 0">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </p>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sometag">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to you input:

```
<para>
  text before
  <sometag>Content</sometag>
  text after
</para>
```

produces:

```
<p>
    text before
    </p><div>Content</div><p>
    text after
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a template that matches `text()` nodes of elements. That way, you exploit the fact that when a child element is among the text content of an element, this results in several text nodes for this element.

So, the content of the `para` element you have shown actually is:

```
[text node, "text before"] [sometag node] [text node, "text after"]
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="para|sometag">
         <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template> 

   <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="parent::sometag">
            <div>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </div>
         </xsl:when>

         <xsl:when test="parent::para">
            <p>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </p>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
  text before
  </p>
<div>Content</div>
<p>
  text after
</p>
```

Comment: Hm, yes some sort of similar approach might be useful. I'll wait for other people's opinions though.

Comment: That's fine. Using the grouping functionality of XSLT 2.0 is fine, too - but less straightforward in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 2.0 I think you want to replace your template matching `para` with

```
<xsl:template match="para">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="sometag">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::sometag)]"/>
    </p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last() and self::sometag]"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```